# Including current year in Header file with Gulp Header

Tags: javascript, date, gulp, gulp-header

Is there anyway to print out the current year in a header file using [Gulp Header](https://github.com/tracker1/gulp-header)?

Here's an example of what I'd like to do:

```
var banner = ['/**',
  ' * Copyright (c) 2014 Cofey',
  ' * <%= pkg.name %> - <%= pkg.description %>',
  ' * @version v<%= pkg.version %>',
  ' * @link <%= pkg.homepage %>',
  ' * @license <%= pkg.license %>',
  ' */',
  ''].join('\n');
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like gulp uses lodash templates; you should be able to include arbitrary JavaScript:

```
var banner = ['/**',
  ' * Copyright (c) <%= new Date().getFullYear() %> Cofey',
  ' * <%= pkg.name %> - <%= pkg.description %>',
  ' * @version v<%= pkg.version %>',
  ' * @link <%= pkg.homepage %>',
  ' * @license <%= pkg.license %>',
  ' */',
  ''].join('\n');
```

Answer (score 0):

Since [Node.js 4.4.1](http://node.green/#template-literals) [ES6 template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) are supported:

```
var banner = `/**
 * Copyright (c) ${new Date().getFullYear()} Cofey
 * ${pkg.name} - ${pkg.description}
 * @version v${pkg.version}
 * @link ${pkg.homepage}
 * @license ${pkg.license}
 */\n`;
```